# glx not available in X.org (with mga driver)

Tags: graphics, xorg

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my HP Proliant Microserver Gen8.

I installed xserver-xorg-video-mga manually to get the full list of resolutions available. I cannot start Steam and the problem seems to be glx related (when I was using the live-system via boot-USB-stick I could start steam):

**steam**

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/an/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
awk: /home/andreas/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1476379980)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1476379980)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1476379980)
OpenGL GLX extension not supported by displayMain.cpp (309) : Assertion Failed: Fatal Error: OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display
Assert( Assertion Failed: Fatal Error: OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ):Main.cpp:309

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1476379980)
assert_20161125214533_5.dmp[3516]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20161125214533_5.dmp
assert_20161125214533_5.dmp[3516]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20161125214533_5.dmp[3516]: response: CrashID=bp-0fbd503f-f4cb-4581-94b4-d38372161125
assert_20161125214533_5.dmp[3516]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20161125214533_5.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-0fbd503f-f4cb-4581-94b4-d38372161125''
```

**lspci | grep VGA**

```
01:00.1 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200EH
```

**glxinfo -v**

```
name of display: :0.0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

**lshw -C video**

```
 *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: MGA G200EH
       vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f9000000-f9ffffff memory:fbee0000-fbee3fff memory:fb000000-fb7fffff
```

**xorg.0.log**

```
[    15.124] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[    15.124] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    15.124] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    15.124] Current Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:39:52 UTC 2016 x86_64
[    15.124] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet nosplash
[    15.124] Build Date: 02 November 2016  10:06:10PM
[    15.124] xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    15.124] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[    15.124]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    15.124] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    15.124] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Nov 25 21:14:44 2016
[    15.128] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    15.128] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    15.128] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    15.128] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    15.128] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    15.131] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    15.131] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    15.131] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    15.131] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    15.131] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    15.131] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    15.131]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.131] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    15.131]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.131] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    15.131]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.131] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    15.131]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.131] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    15.131]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.131] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    15.131] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    15.131] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    15.132] (II) Loader magic: 0x562e972f1dc0
[    15.132] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    15.132]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    15.132]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[    15.132]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[    15.132]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    15.133] (++) using VT number 7

[    15.133] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    15.134] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:1) 102b:0533:103c:3381 rev 0, Mem @ 0xf9000000/16777216, 0xfbee0000/16384, 0xfb000000/8388608
[    15.134] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[    15.134] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    15.134] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    15.135] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    15.288] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    15.288]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    15.288]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    15.289] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  367.57  Mon Oct  3 20:28:17 PDT 2016
[    15.291] (==) Matched mga as autoconfigured driver 0
[    15.291] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[    15.291] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[    15.291] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    15.291] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    15.291] (II) LoadModule: "mga"
[    15.291] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/mga_drv.so
[    15.294] (II) Module mga: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.294]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 1.6.4
[    15.294]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    15.294]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    15.294] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    15.294] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    15.295] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.295]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.18.4
[    15.295]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    15.295]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    15.295] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    15.296] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    15.296] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.296]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 0.4.4
[    15.296]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    15.296]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    15.296] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    15.296] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    15.297] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.297]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.3.4
[    15.297]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    15.297]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    15.297] (II) MGA: driver for Matrox chipsets: mga2064w, mga1064sg, mga2164w,
    mga2164w AGP, mgag100, mgag100 PCI, mgag200, mgag200 PCI,
    mgag200 SE A PCI, mgag200 SE B PCI, mgag200 EV Maxim,
    mgag200 ER SH7757, mgag200 eW Nuvoton, mgag200eH, mgag400, mgag550
[    15.297] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    15.297] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    15.297] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    15.365] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    15.365] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    15.365] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    15.365] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    15.365] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    15.365] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    15.365] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.365]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    15.365]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    15.366] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    15.366] (II) Loading sub module "vgahw"
[    15.366] (II) LoadModule: "vgahw"
[    15.366] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvgahw.so
[    15.367] (II) Module vgahw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.367]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 0.1.0
[    15.367]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    15.367] (--) MGA(0): Chipset: "mgag200eH"
[    15.367] (II) MGA(0): HW cursor is not supported with video redirection onG200 server chips.
 If you don't intend to use video redirection enable with Option "HWCursor" "On"
[    15.367] xf86TokenToOptinfo: table is NULL
[    15.367] xf86TokenToOptinfo: table is NULL
[    15.367] (==) MGA(0): Using SW cursor
[    15.367] (--) MGA(0): Linear framebuffer at 0xF9000000
[    15.367] (--) MGA(0): MMIO registers at 0xFBEE0000
[    15.367] (--) MGA(0): Pseudo-DMA transfer window at 0xFB000000
[    15.367] (II) MGA(0): MAPPED Framebuffer F9000000 800000 to 7FEE806D8000.
[    15.401] (II) MGA(0): UNMAPPING framebuffer 0x7FEE806D8000, 0x800000.
[    15.401] (II) MGA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    15.401] (==) MGA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    15.401] (==) MGA(0): RGB weight 888
[    15.401] (==) MGA(0): Using AGP 1x mode
[    15.401] (==) MGA(0): Using XAA acceleration
[    15.401] (--) MGA(0): Video BIOS info block at offset 0x079E0
[    15.401] (==) MGA(0): VideoRAM: 8128 kByte
[    15.401] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[    15.401] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[    15.401] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[    15.401] (II) Loading sub module "i2c"
[    15.401] (II) LoadModule: "i2c"
[    15.401] (II) Module "i2c" already built-in
[    15.401] (II) MGA(0): MAPPED Framebuffer F9000000 7f0000 to 7FEE806E8000.
[    15.401] (II) MGA(0): vgaHWGetIOBase: hwp->IOBase is 0x03d0
[    15.404] (II) MGA(0): I2C bus "DDC P1" initialized.
[    15.404] (II) MGA(0): I2C device "DDC P1:ddc2" registered at address 0xA0.
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): I2C monitor info
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): Manufacturer: AOC  Model: 2460  Serial#: 294
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): Year: 2013  Week: 21
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): Analog Display Input,  Input Voltage Level: 0.700/0.700 V
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): Sync:  Separate
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 53  vert.: 30
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): DPMS capabilities: Off; RGB/Color Display
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): redX: 0.650 redY: 0.329   greenX: 0.331 greenY: 0.622
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): blueX: 0.151 blueY: 0.053   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): Supported established timings:
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 720x400@70Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 640x480@60Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 640x480@67Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 640x480@72Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 640x480@75Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 800x600@56Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 800x600@60Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 800x600@72Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 800x600@75Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 832x624@75Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 1024x768@70Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): Supported standard timings:
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): #0: hsize: 1920  vsize 1080  refresh: 60  vid: 49361
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): #1: hsize: 1680  vsize 1050  refresh: 60  vid: 179
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): #2: hsize: 1440  vsize 900  refresh: 60  vid: 149
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): #3: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): #4: hsize: 1280  vsize 960  refresh: 60  vid: 16513
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): #5: hsize: 1280  vsize 720  refresh: 60  vid: 49281
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): clock: 148.5 MHz   Image Size:  531 x 299 mm
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1084  v_sync_end 1089 v_blanking: 1125 v_border: 0
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): Ranges: V min: 50 V max: 76 Hz, H min: 30 H max: 83 kHz, PixClock max 175 MHz
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): Monitor name: G2460
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): Serial No: C02D5BA000294
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): EDID (in hex):
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0):   00ffffffffffff0005e3602426010000
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0):   1517010368351e782a9de5a654549f26
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0):   0d5054bfef00d1c0b300950081808140
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0):   81c001010101023a801871382d40582c
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0):   4500132b2100001e000000fd00324c1e
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0):   5311000a202020202020000000fc0047
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0):   323436300a20202020202020000000ff
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0):   00433032443542413030303239340053
[    15.461] (II) MGA(0): end of monitor info
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): UNMAPPING framebuffer 0x7FEE806E8000, 0x7F0000.
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 9312
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    15.462] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
[    15.463] (==) MGA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    15.463] (==) MGA(0): Min pixel clock is 17 MHz
[    15.463] (--) MGA(0): Max pixel clock is 203 MHz
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): <default monitor>: Using hsync range of 30.00-83.00 kHz
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): <default monitor>: Using vrefresh range of 50.00-76.00 Hz
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): <default monitor>: Using maximum pixel clock of 175.00 MHz
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Estimated virtual size for aspect ratio 1.7667 is 1920x1080
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Clock range:  17.75 to 203.40 MHz
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "640x350" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "320x175" (bad mode clock/interlace/doublescan)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "640x400" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "320x200" (bad mode clock/interlace/doublescan)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "720x400" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "360x200" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "320x240" (bad mode clock/interlace/doublescan)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "320x240" (bad mode clock/interlace/doublescan)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "320x240" (bad mode clock/interlace/doublescan)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "640x480" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "320x240" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "800x600" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "400x300" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1024x768i" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "512x384i" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1024x768" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "512x384" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1280x960" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "640x480" (hsync out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1280x1024" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "640x512" (hsync out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1600x1200" (height too large for virtual size)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1600x1200" (height too large for virtual size)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1600x1200" (height too large for virtual size)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "800x600" (hsync out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1600x1200" (height too large for virtual size)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "800x600" (hsync out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1600x1200" (height too large for virtual size)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "800x600" (hsync out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1792x1344" (insufficient memory for mode)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1792x1344" (insufficient memory for mode)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "896x672" (hsync out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1856x1392" (insufficient memory for mode)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "928x696" (hsync out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1856x1392" (insufficient memory for mode)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "928x696" (hsync out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1920x1440" (insufficient memory for mode)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "960x720" (hsync out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1920x1440" (insufficient memory for mode)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "960x720" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1152x864" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "576x432" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1152x864" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "576x432" (vrefresh out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1152x864" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "576x432" (hsync out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1360x768" (monitor doesn't support reduced blanking)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1400x1050" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1400x1050" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1400x1050" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "700x525" (hsync out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1600x1024" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1680x1050" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1680x1050" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1680x1050" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1680x1050" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1680x1050" (bad mode clock/interlace/doublescan)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "840x525" (hsync out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1920x1080" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1920x1200" (insufficient memory for mode)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1920x1440" (insufficient memory for mode)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "960x720" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "2048x1536" (insufficient memory for mode)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1024x768" (hsync out of range)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "2048x1536" (insufficient memory for mode)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1024x768" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "2048x1536" (insufficient memory for mode)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1024x768" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using driver mode "1920x1080" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using driver mode "1920x1080" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using driver mode "1680x1050" (mode requires too much memory bandwidth)
[    15.463] (WW) MGA(0): Shrinking virtual size estimate from 1920x1080 to 1280x1024
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1400x1050" (height too large for virtual size)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using driver mode "1440x900" (width too large for virtual size)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1440x900" (width too large for virtual size)
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Not using default mode "1360x768" (width too large for virtual size)
[    15.463] (--) MGA(0): Has SDRAM
[    15.463] (--) MGA(0): Virtual size is 1280x1024 (pitch 1280)
[    15.463] (**) MGA(0): *Driver mode "1280x1024": 135.0 MHz, 80.0 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[    15.463] (II) MGA(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz ez)
[    15.464] (**) MGA(0): Display dimensions: (530, 300) mm
[    15.464] (**) MGA(0): DPI set to (61, 86)
[    15.464] (II) MGA(0): YDstOrg is set to 0
[    15.464] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    15.464] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    15.464] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    15.465] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.465]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    15.465]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    15.465] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    15.465] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    15.465] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    15.465] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    15.465] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    15.465] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    15.465] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    15.465] (II) Unloading vesa
[    15.465] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    15.465] (II) MGA(0): MAPPED Framebuffer F9000000 7f0000 to 7FEE81115000.
[    15.465] (II) MGA(0): vgaHWGetIOBase: hwp->IOBase is 0x03d0
[    15.468] (--) MGA(0): 64 DWORD fifo
[    15.479] (==) MGA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    15.479] (EE) MGA(0): Static buffer allocation failed, not initializing the DRI
[    15.479] (EE) MGA(0): Need at least 15360 kB video memory at this resolution, bit depth
[    15.483] (II) MGA(0): Using 601 lines for offscreen memory.
[    15.483] (==) MGA(0): Backing store enabled
[    15.483] (==) MGA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    15.486] (==) MGA(0): DPMS enabled
[    15.486] (WW) MGA(0): Direct rendering disabled
[    15.487] (==) RandR enabled
[    15.492] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    15.495] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

Comment: Looks like it's not a gaming machine. What do you think we should do about it? Is there a question you wanted to ask?

Comment: Yes - it is no game-machine - but when I used the live-system via USB before installing Ubuntu Steam worked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was nvidia drivers interfered with the mesa-drivers.

So the solution was:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo update-alternatives --remove gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf
```

You can verify using glxgears that it works. Found the solution at https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1904638.html